# Why does label text on axis disappear in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a label for my my y-axis and I have problems displaying it.

```
SVG.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("x", 100)
      .attr("y", 100)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Sepal Width (cm)");
```

When I use the code above I cannot display my label, but when i remove

```
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
```

I can see my text.

Why is this?

Comment: did this solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, it did, I was very busy and your comment reminded me to mark your answer as best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `rotate` rotates the text relative to the origin so your text is out of the canvas. You have two options here:

Use translate to position the text before the rotation

```
.attr("transform", "translate(100, 100) rotate(-90)")
```

or you add the optional x and y parameters to rotate()

```
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90 100 100)")
```

Comment: Good answer, and @Vanquiza also you can try .attr("transform", "rotate(-5)") or similar small angles to see how rotation is done unfortunatelly around origin for such code!